# Dynamic table issue in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to build a table within Marketing Cloud, where I have five rows and 2 columns.
Adding below code in content
[image]

but automatically if condition adding outside of table.
[image]

I only want the row of the table to display when there are values.

Comment: I will recommend you to paste the actual code instead of screenshots, as this makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way to pull the data that you are working with, but since you haven't posted anything about the data structure, I can only help you with the conditionals. Try this:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Amount</td><td>Description</td></tr>
%%[ 
set @amount1 = Amount1
set @description1 = Description1
set @amount2 = Amount2
set @description2 = Description2
if not empty(@amount1) or not empty(@description1) then ]%% 

<tr>
<td>%%=v(@amount1)=%%</td><td>%%=v(@description1)=%%</td>
</tr>

%%[endif 
if not empty(@amount2) or not empty(@description2) then ]%% 

<tr>
<td>%%=v(@amount2)=%%</td><td>%%=v(@description2)=%%</td>
</tr>

%%[ endif ]%%

</table>
```

Are you sure you want the row to be displayed if either Amount or Description are available, or should it only be displayed when both those values are available?

Comment: Working Thank you